# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference : as3

Tags: c#, null, object-reference

. pls help me ... if i debug below code then it is showing **Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference** ..how to solve it

```
protected function upload_itemClickHandler(event:ItemClickEvent):void
    {
      if(upload.selectedValue == "allupload")
        {
        theModel.removeAllViews();
        //ModuleLbl.text = headerText;
        theModel.uploadStatusMessage = "";
        theModel.adminStatusMessage = "";
        var gallComp:ManageGallery = new ManageGallery();
        gallComp.theModel = theModel;
        theModel.AdminUIComponent.addChild(gallComp as DisplayObject);
        theModel.adminObj["theTaskName"] = "GalleryRepository";
        theModel.adminObj["userID"] = theModel.activeUserObj.UserID;
        theModel.adminObj["isAdminLogin"] = theModel.isAdminLogin;
        theModel.theAdminEvt.dispatch();
        theModel.tempAdminParams = theModel.adminObj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the variables you are trying to read from or write to is `Null`, i.e. has no value yet. The line number in your error message should tell you where this occurs.

You can avoid this by using for instance:

```
if(yourVariable != null){
    // do something with the variable
}
```

My guess is that this stems from `upload.selectedValue` - are you sure this is set? You can try replacing the first part of your code with the following:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(upload.selectedValue)
   && (upload.selectedValue == "allupload"))
{
    // do stuff with theModel
}
```

If that removes the error, you just have to figure out why `upload.selectedValue` is not set.